# Using md-select, pass the entire object of an ng-repeat item, not just a string

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, pug, angular-material, angular-ngmodel

I have made a form with Angular Material that uses a dropdown list to choose from an array of `book` objects, with names and IDs, for the ultimate purpose of trading it for another book in my collection. Here is what my typical trade object looks like:

```
var tradeItem = {
  wanted: {
    user: 'barryjohnson',
    bookId: 'foo1bar2'
  },
  offered: {
    user: 'dangraham',
    bookId: 'bar7baz8'
  },
};
```

I want to save the entire object to my `ng-model` in my select menu, so I want the ng-repeat to refer to the entire array object. This way I can make a simple subsequent request to my database.

At the moment it is only saving the title, which is what have inside my `md-option` tag.

Here is my view:

```
md-dialog(aria-label='Trade', ng-cloak='')
  form
    md-toolbar
      .md-toolbar-tools
        h2 Propose a Trade
        span(flex='')
    md-dialog-content(style='max-width:800px;max-height:810px; ')
      .md-dialog-content
        p Which of your books would you like to trade for '{{userClickedBook.title}}'?
        p {{selected}}
        md-input-container.md-block
          label(for="mySelect") Your Books
          md-select(name="mySelect", ng-model='selected')
            md-option(ng-repeat="book in usersBooks") {{book.title}}
        div(layout='row')
          md-button(ng-click='cancelDialog()', style='margin-right: 20px;') Cancel
          md-button.md-primary(ng-click='save()', ng-disabled='myForm.$invalid', layout='', layout-align='center end') Ok
```

So, how can I bind the entire object, so that `$scope.selected` is like the above object `tradeItem`, instead of just a single string (the content of `md-option`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Won't this work for you?

```
 <md-option ng-repeat="book in userBooks" ng-value="book">
            {{book.title}}
          </md-option>
```

Comment: I must have had a brain freeze to miss the `value` attribute, thanks.

Comment: You are allowed, we all have them from time to time! :)

Comment: This passes the book value in as a String, not an object. So you either have to parse it after, or there is another way to pass it in...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187358/change-selected-item-in-md-select-programatically.

Use `ng-value="book"` instead of `value={{book}}`.

Comment: Thanks a  lot @Liron your comment has saved me a lot of time troubleshooting some watch function