# change selected item in md-select programmatically

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to initially (on page load) set the current schoolclass item in the md-select.

This code sets the selected schoolclass but it is not reflected in the `md-select` visually.

```
$scope.selectedSchoolclass = schoolclasses.length > 0 ? schoolclasses[0] : null;

<md-input-container>
    <label>Schoolclasses</label>
    <md-select ng-model="selectedSchoolclass"  md-on-close="getPupils()">
        <md-option ng-repeat="s in schoolclasses" ng-value="{{s}}">
            {{s.schoolclassNumber}}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

When I use `md-selected="$first"` then it is selected visually in the `md-select` but I get an error from a computed property which seem to evaluate first just before the $first. Thus I cannot set the first schoolclass as the selected schoolclass from html. I have to do it via JS in the controller.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close.
Just change

```
<md-option ng-repeat="s in schoolclasses" ng-value="{{s}}">
```

To

```
<md-option ng-repeat="s in schoolclasses" ng-value="s">
```

ng-value is already expecting an angular expression ([see here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue)), so you don't need to evaluate the expression with {{}}.

EDIT:

And also, I assume you meant:

```
$scope.selectedSchoolclass = $scope.schoolclasses.length > 0 ? $scope.schoolclasses[0] : null;
```

schoolclasses needs to be $scope.schoolclasses because you reference it in your template.

Comment: argh... yeah I overlooked that curly brackets, thanks.

Comment: how to get selected value in md-select?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to add `ng-model-options` and specify the `trackBy` on some identifying property - id, name or schoolclassNumber probably.

Also, as make sure to remove the `{{}}` on `ng-value`.

```
<md-select ng-model="selectedSchoolclass"  md-on-close="getPupils()" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.schoolclassNumber'}">
    <md-option ng-repeat="s in schoolclasses" ng-value="s" ng-bind="s.schoolclassNumber"></md-option>
</md-select>
```

I am also not sure if assigning `null` can be a problem here, maybe try `undefined`.

It is also good practice to specify a `track by` on the `ng-repeat`. Again, use your identifying property.

```
<md-option ng-repeat="s in schoolclasses track by s.schoolclassNumber" ng-value="s" ng-bind="s.schoolclassNumber"></md-option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your md-select like this

```
  <md-select ng-model="selectedSchoolclass"  md-on-close="getPupils()">
        <md-option ng-repeat="s in schoolclasses" ng-value="{{s}}">
            {{s.schoolclassNumber}} ng-selected="{{ selectedSchoolclass.indexOf(s.schoolclassNumber) > -1}}"
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
```